# Android: Camera Activity, Image rotation

Tags: android, android-camera

I made a Camera Activity with `SurfaceView` and Camera Classes.

Two fragments: when we take the picture in first, it moves to second fragment and it shows the picture just taken. 
(Just like `new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)`).

The problem occurs when the picture is shown.
When I take the picture in portrait mode, it shows it fine, just like the first picture.

[image]

However, when I take the picture in landscape mode, it shows it like the following second picture.
[image]

But I want it to look like the third one.

[image]

I think the problem occurs because just because I flipped the camera in landscape mode, the phone does not know it. (It's obvious) But when I turn on the rotation, it crashes when it changes to landscape mode when I rotate the phone.

Is there any way the camera automatically knows that the user is taking the picture in landscape mode just like normal android camera application?
Or any solutions to my problem will be fine.

Comment: ok ...? but does that really matter..? i saw many questions tagged not asking about IDE. you sound like i caused you a problem or something ;;

Comment: I know, but they're not supposed to. There's also a meta post on the topic (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561). And you didn't do anything wrong, this happens a lot. The comment is to make it more visible in an attempt to reduce misuse of tags. Mainly because tags also affect question visibility, and the Android tag has a lot more watchers than the Android studio tag

Comment: will keep that in mind next time. didn't know such an etiquette.

Comment: Could you also provide details on the crash, a stacktrace would assist in gaining insight into the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you problem is simpler than you think.

So in **portrait** mode, your device takes a photo, capturing e.g. 1080p photo as a vertical image. When taking a photo in **landscape** (*horizontal mode*) in your `first fragment` (with the `SurfaceView`), you are still capturing a photo as a e.g. 1080p photo.

When viewing the photo on your `second fragment`, **your device does not know which orientation the photo is**, by default. It can just as well be a portrait photo. Thus, when taking the image, you **need to** add an additional attribute to the photo image (or Bundle to the second fragment) telling the **second fragment** to change `orientation` and view the image in a specific `orientation`.

*Based on the limited information*, I conclude that you have no errors in your code (with exception of the crash you mentioned - which I believe is related to saving/restoring `instanceState` from bundle) - but simply having to view the image in the correct orientation.

Comment: but I gave Camera.PictureCallback method to get byte data from the picture I just taken. And send byte array to second fragment and show it through Bitmap and ImageView.
Is it possible to get the information about the orientation about the photo??

Comment: I am not sure if there is an easier way, but I would get the current device orientation from the configuration, which would also be the same orientation as the photo. Then when viewing the photo, set that orientation (with some matrix operation if you will) to view the photo in the correct orientation. I hope this helps

Comment: @Peter kindly accept the answer if it was the solution to your problem.

Comment: I solved it by receiving the slope by OreintationEventListener.
what do you think?

Comment: @Peter that is one way of doing it. Glad you got it solved though :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, picture orientation is saved in the EXIF header of the jpeg image. Some devices won't set this flag for you in camera API, but all have [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) class. The [support library](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html) makes this even easier.

Even if the flag is set correctly, the fragment that shows the picture must know how to apply it for correct display. The easiest solution is use [Glyde](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or some other library.

Comment: but the picture I take is only setted in data, not saved yet until I press save button.
I show it in the second fragment by sending byte array and make it bitmap and then Imageview. Is it possible to get EXIFinterface?

Comment: Exif interaface is called by giving its parameter as file path but since it's not saved yet... I thought that using the interface is impossible.  Would there be another way?

Comment: The *support library* can work with byte array (you should use the [constructor that takes InputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html#ExifInterface(java.io.InputStream))).

Comment: Actually [the article in Google Developers blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html) that introduced the support library is very good.

Comment: Thank u! Must have missed something :) Will try!